# Create a function to find the length of a vector WITHOUT using length()

Tags: r

I already tried `max(seq_along(x))` but I need it to also return 0 if we, let's say, inputted `numeric(0)`.

So yeah, it works for anything else other than numeric(0). This is what I have so far:

```
my_length <- function(x){
  max(seq_along(x))
}
```

Comment: @RitchieSacramento not allowed to use tail :(

Comment: Edit your question, what other constraints do you have? Assume, head is not allowed, right?

Comment: As you noticed, `seq_along()` works except for empty vectors. So just add an `if` that tests if the input is empty.

Answer (score 5):

You can just include a `0` to the `max()` call in your attempt:

```
my_length <- function(x) max(0, seq_along(x))

my_length(10:1)
[1] 10
my_length(NULL)
[1] 0
my_length(numeric())
[1] 0
```

Comment: what does the 0 do? Like what is the explanation? Thanks

Comment: The default behavior of `max()` is to return `-Inf` if the input is empty, including `0` means that is what is returned instead (because e.g. `max(0, integer(0))` = `0`).

Answer (score 4):

Using *forloop*:

```
my_length <- function(x){
  l = 0
  for(i in x) l <- l + 1  
  return(l)
}

x <- numeric(0)
my_length(x)
# [1] 0

x <- 1:10
my_length(x)
# [1] 10
```

Another option:

```
my_length <- function(x) nrow(matrix(x))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `NROW()`:

```r
len <- \(x) NROW(x)
```

Examples:

```r
len(numeric(0))
#> [1] 0

len(letters)
#> [1] 26

len(c(3, 0, 9, 1))
#> [1] 4
```

---

From the documentation:

> nrow and ncol return the number of rows or columns present in x. NCOL and NROW do the same treating a vector as 1-column matrix, even a 0-length vector ...

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few more [functional programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) approaches:

1. Using **mapping** and **summation**:

   ```
   length = function (x) {
       sum(vapply(x, \(.) 1L, integer(1L)))
   }
   ```
2. Using **reduction**:

   ```
   length = function (x) {
       Reduce(\(x, .) x + 1L, x, 0L)
   }
   ```
3. Using **recursion**:

   ```
   length = function (x, len = 0L) {
       if (is_empty(x)) len else Recall(x[-1L], len + 1L)
   }
   ```

   Alas, the last one needs to define the helper function and that is unfortunately not trivial without using `length()`:

   ```
   is_empty = function (x) {
       is.null(x) || identical(x, vector(typeof(x), 0L))
   }
   ```